# Is there a way to set the max value of a numericInput() as the value of another numericInput()?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with two `numericInput()`. One for the minimum value and the second for the maximum value. Is it possible to set the max value of the minimum as the value of the maximum?

```
    library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("filter")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$filter<-renderUI({
  "range"=tagList(
  numericInput("obs", "Min:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("obs2", "Max:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
)
})

  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `renderUI()`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("obs1"),
  numericInput("obs2", "Max:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ 
    input$obs 
  })

  output$obs1 <- renderUI({
    val <- min(input$obs, as.numeric(input$obs2))
    numericInput("obs", "Min:", val, min = 1, max = as.numeric(input$obs2))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I made some alterations to my code in order to bring it closer to my original issue.

Comment: ok, i am not sure i understand your edit. Is it an additional question? Why are both Inputs in the renderUI?.......(Wild guess - as i dont know the use case - you can also use a range from a sliderinput - http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/slider-bar-and-slider-range.html, maybe thats also of interest)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The "filter" contains many shiny widgets that are used based on a user input in my original case. I use switch for this. The original question was slightly different from what I actually wanted. Is it possible to adjust your answer?